# ProxyApi NodeJs (Upload de ficheiros)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Boas tardes, estou a criar um Proxy para uma aplicação. O que se pretender é centralizar um conjunto de API's e fazer o reencaminhameto dos pedidos.

Estou a fazer um exemplo básico em nodejs. Onde tenho 2 servidores:

- Servidor 1 (Proxy)
- Servidor 2 (Outra API)

Index:

```
const http = require("http");

const appServer1 = require("./server1");
const appServer2 = require("./server2");

const server1 = http.createServer(appServer1);
const server2 = http.createServer(appServer2);

server1.listen(3001);
server2.listen(3002);
```

Servidor 1:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/upload", function(req, res) {
  res.json({});
});

module.exports = app;
```

Servidor 2:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/uploadOther", function(req, res) {
  res.json({});
});

module.exports = app;
```

O que queria fazer era encaminhar por exemplo o pedido http://localhost:3001/upload para http://localhost:3002/uploadOther, sem ter que guardar o ficheiro por exemplo. Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Talvez o *NodeJs* não seja a melhor opção para *proxy reverso*, mas… Você pode tentar com o [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) + ExpressJS

Comment: da uma olhada neste exmplo https://itnext.io/hosting-multiple-apps-on-the-same-server-implement-a-reverse-proxy-with-node-a4e213497345